# DOM not updated after array changes with ngFor

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngfor

Wanted behaviour: when pressing stop button, an audiolink is generated, added to an array of which ngFor adds to the list and the DOM is updated.

Actual behaviour: the audioclip is not being added to the list directly after clicking the stop button. Only when invoking a new event such as clicking the stop button again it is added to the DOM by ngFor (and works fine).

Why is ngFor not detecting the change in the audioUrls array?

app-component.html:

```
<button (click)="startRecording()">Start Recording</button>
<button (click)="stopRecording()">Stop Recording</button>
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let audioUrl of audioUrls">
    <audio controls [src]="audioUrl"></audio> 
  </li>
</ul>
```

app-component.ts:

```
import { RecordService } from './record.service';
import { Component, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';
import { SafeUrl, SafeResourceUrl } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { OnInit } from '@angular/core/src/metadata/lifecycle_hooks';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  title = 'app';

  audioUrls: SafeResourceUrl[];

  constructor(private recordService:RecordService){
  }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.recordService.audioUrlsChanged.subscribe(list => this.audioUrls = list);
  }

  startRecording(){
    if(this.recordService.audioRecorder){
      this.recordService.audioRecorder.start()
      console.log(this.recordService.audioRecorder.state);
    }
  }

  stopRecording(){
    if(this.recordService.audioRecorder){
      this.recordService.audioRecorder.stop()
      console.log(this.recordService.audioRecorder.state);
    }
  }
}
```

service:

```
import { WindowRefService } from './window-ref.service';
import { Injectable, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeResourceUrl } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { SafeUrl } from '@angular/platform-browser';
declare var MediaRecorder: any;

@Injectable()
export class RecordService {

  audioRecorder:any;
  chunks:any[] = [];
  audioUrls:SafeResourceUrl[] = [];
  audioUrlsChanged= new Subject<SafeResourceUrl[]>();

  constructor(private windowRef:WindowRefService, private domSanitizer: DomSanitizer) { 
    this.audioRecorder = this.windowRef.nativeWindow.navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia (
      // constraints - only audio needed for this app
      {
         audio: true
      }).then(
        stream => {
          this.audioRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);

          this.audioRecorder.ondataavailable = (e) => {
            this.chunks.push(e.data);
          }

          this.audioRecorder.onstop = (e) => {
            let blob = new Blob(this.chunks, { 'type' : 'audio/ogg; codecs=opus' });
            this.chunks = []; //reset buffer
            let url:SafeResourceUrl = this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(this.windowRef.nativeWindow.URL.createObjectURL(blob));
            this.audioUrls.push(url);
            this.audioUrlsChanged.next(this.audioUrls.slice());        
          }
      });     
  }
```

(Window refservice is just a wrapper for the window object)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The audioRecorder onstop method happens outside the Angular context, as it's an event generated by an external library outside Angular.

So, Angular does not update the view. You would have to run that in an ngZone.run.

1. Add a variable `zone` to the constructor of your service, type `NgZone`.
2. Inside the stop event, wrap the code inside a `this.zone.run()`.

Alternatively, you can call a ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges().

See eg [this blog post](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/01/zones-in-angular-2.htm%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bl) for a better explanation: